# Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed when trying to mock and verify a simple test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I am trying to execute a simple mock and verify

```
[TestClass]
    public class PublisherTests
    {
        Mock<IPublisher> myPublisherMock;
        Publisher publisher;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {


            myPublisherMock = new Mock<IPublisher>();

            publisher = new Publisher(myPublisherMock.Object);

        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void ShouldReturnNegativeWhenMsgIsInvalid1()
        {
            string msg = "abc";
            long result = -1;
            myPublisherMock.Setup(m => m.GetMessageCount(msg)).Returns(result).Verifiable();
            publisher.GetMessageCount(msg);
            myPublisherMock.Verify(m => m.GetMessageCount(msg));

        }

    }
```

but it always throws exception

> Moq.MockException: ' Expected invocation on the mock at least once,
>   but was never performed: m =>
>   m.GetQueueMessageCount1(It.IsAny())
>
> ```
> Performed invocations:
>
>    Mock<IPublisher:1> (m):
>    No invocations performed.
> ```

Actual Method

```
public class Publisher : IPublisher
{   
 private IPublisher MyPublisher { get; set; }
    public Publisher(IPublisher publisher)
    {
        MyPublisher = publisher;
    }

    public long GetMessageCount(string msg)
   {
    long result = 0;

    try
    {
        if (msg == "abc")
            throw new Exception();

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var p = ex.Message;
        return result = -1;
    }


   }
}
```

Unable to identify where I am going wrong.

Comment: @Nkosi i did call the mock but still throws error .

Comment: Where did you call the mock?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen please check the latest edit .publisher.GetMessageCount(msg); - I believe this is the one your mentioned right ?

Comment: No, that calls a similar method on a Publisher object, not the mock. You did pass the mock *to* that publisher object but we don't see what is inside the GetMessageCount on Publisher.

Comment: @Nkosi I have added the Publisher class details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the shown example and assuming this was an attempt to test a decorator pattern

For example

```
public interface IPublisher {
    long GetMessageCount(string msg);
}

public class Publisher : IPublisher {
    private readonly IPublisher publisher;

    public Publisher(IPublisher publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public long GetMessageCount(string msg) {
        long result = 0;
        try {
            if (msg == "abc")
                throw new Exception();

            result = publisher.GetMessageCount(msg);
            return result;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            var p = ex.Message;
            return result = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Where the test wants to test the expected behavior of when an exception is thrown then there is no need to setup the member on the mock since it is not expected to be invoked.

You can however verify that it was never called.

For example

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldReturnNegativeWhenMsgIsAbc() {
    //Arrange
    var myPublisherMock = new Mock<IPublisher>();

    long expected = -1;

    var subject = new Publisher(myPublisherMock.Object);

    //Act
    var actual = subject.GetMessageCount("abc");

    //Assert
    actual.Should().Be(expected); //FluentAssertion
    myPublisherMock.Verify(_ => _.GetMessageCount(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Never);
}
```